# How to handle Zapier authentiation failure propertly?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'm trying to display a friendly message on the authentication failure prompt in Zapier. Throwing an Error or HaltedError is always showing the stack trace and the console logs which I'd like to get rid of. Is there a way to only display a custom message we specify?

[image]

Comment: can you show your code for how you're making the request to the `/access` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Zapier has updated their UI recently. After "What happened", it now says, "You are seeing this because you are an admin". I take this to mean that the end users will not see the stack trace or console. 
[image: authentication failed: Invalid credentials What ahppened (You are seeing this because you are an admin): ... etc]